# Update a column based on the highest value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a SQL-database with a table called 'PP_Match' with a couple of columns in it.

ID, Position_1, Position_2, Round and Draw_size

In this table ID, Position_1 and Position_2 is a composite key together!

I want to update the Draw_size column, based upon the highest value in column 'Round'. To make this extra fun, the Draw_size column should display a knock-out draw (Elimination Draw), that you use in any kind of sport.

So if the highest value in Round for a specific ID is 1, then I want to display '2' in Draw_size. If the highest value is 2 then draw_size is 4, and a 3 in Round column would return a 8 in draw_size and so on (4=16, 5=32, 6=64, 7=128).

I want to update all rows of a specific ID.

Let say that ID 001 has 5 rows in the database with the higest value in "Round" as 3, then I want to update all the 5 rows with a Draw_size value of 8...

I've tried and failed multiple times...

Thank you guys for your assitance!!!

/ Fred

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work

```
UPDATE PP_MATCH pp1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT ID, MAX(ROUND) as Max_Round FROM PP_MATCH GROUP BY ID) A 
ON A.ID = pp1.ID
SET pp1.Draw_size = POW(2, Max_Round)
```

Comment: You are a life saver!!!
This did it...

I had to change it a little bit, but your query was the key for success!!!

THANKS!!!